# Question and button going blank in Review

Tags: bug, review

I was reviewing on Gaming Stack Exchange today, and saw the following. When the review first loaded, it looked like this.

[image: Normal-looking Late Answer Review]

Then, I scrolled down a bit to see the rest of the page, and it changed to this.

[image: Not so normal-looking Review]

The Question and the I'm Done button both went blank. In the case of the I'm Done button, it didn't even look disabled any more. I scrolled down some more, and it suddenly went back to normal:

[image: Normal-looking-again Review]

The problem kept happening every time I scrolled to that particular spot in the review. Unfortunately, this was the only item in the queue at the time, and I don't have Review privileges on any other SE site, so I can't try again. Doesn't seem to be happening in the Low Quality Posts queue, though.

I'm on Win7 IE10, last updated a couple of hours ago, with no add-ons or toolbars.

**Edit:** This just happened on one of five reviews I ran in the First Posts queue, but not on the other four, nor on the Late Answer review I ran, so it seems to be a bit intermittent.

**Edit 2:** Just happened while editing an answer, so it seems it's not specific to the review page.

[image: Not-so-normal-looking Edit]

Comment: No red coloured free-hand circles?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Bit busy, planned to come back and edit them into that middle image later.

Comment: Seems to be a rendering glitch in IE10, can anyone replicate?